# Conection LG FLATRON E2281 to Dell Inspiron 5558 via HDMI cable

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dell-inspiron, lg-monitor

I've tried to connect my monitor to the laptop for extending the display.
The laptop was detected monitor but nothing display in LG monitor and "check signal cable" was shown. I connected the laptop to SONY Bravia TV via HDMI cable and everything was fine.
For solving the problem I updated drivers then updated windows but nothing changed.

Comment: Does the monitor works with other computers?

Comment: yes, with VGA cable.

Comment: Oh... So you don't know for sure the HDMI port works? I would surely test it even before asking. Here's the thing: If it works with the same cable to your TV then there's nothing wrong with the PC, OS, port or cable. Updating drivers and OS is fine but obviously wouldn't solve it. What remains - the monitor - is where the problem is.